# Custom photo picker для iPad

Tags: ipad, xcode, ios, objective-c

Ищу готовое решение для создания простого фотоальбома для iPad наподобие этого:

[image]

Требования:

- должна быть возможность выделения нескольких фоторафий галочкой (с целью произведения над ними некоего единого действия)
- желательно возможность увеличения по тапу
- должна отображаться сетка фотографий, можно без папок.

Если Вам что-то встречалось из опенсорсных библиотек в работе, просьба дать ссылку и если возможно - краткий комментарий. Если чего-то нет но соответствует общему концепту - тоже можно описать, нужный функционал допилю сам.

Заранее благодарю!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем решил делать через Collection View, как оказалось для данной цели почти все в нем уже есть.